# Redirect whole domain to single page on another domain in Apache Virtual Host

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, mod-rewrite, rewrite

There is lots of information about redirecting a whole domain to another domain but I cannot find any answered questions about redirectly a domain to a specific page on a second domain. This is what I have set up:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain2.org.uk
    ServerAlias domain2.org.uk domain1.co.uk www.domain1.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog logs/mkt-error_log
    CustomLog logs/mkt-access_log common
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain1.co.uk$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain2.org.uk/specific-page/ [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

This does redirect but just to the default page for domain2. How can I change this so that it goes to the specific-page?

Comment: What do you mean by "the default page for domain2"? What redirect(s) are you seeing in the network traffic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain2.org.uk/specific-page/ [L,R=301]
> ```

This already does what you require and redirects *everything* to `https://www.domain2.org.uk/specific-page/` - as stated in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. (Although the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is unnecessarily capturing a back-reference.)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain1.co.uk$ [NC]
> ```

HOWEVER (unless this is a typo in your exemplified code snippet), the condition (that checks that the `Host` header does *not* end with `domain1.co.uk`) will result in a redirect loop (`domain2.org.uk` is obviously *not* `domain1.co.uk`, so the condition is always satisfied). And the following `RewriteRule` redirects *everything*.

The *CondPattern* in this `RewriteCond` directive needs to be changed, by either:

- Removing the `!` (negation) prefix. (Although the trailing `$` would still cause issues with a FQDN that ends in a dot.)
- OR, change to `!domain2\.org\.uk$`

---

But... since you clearly have access to the server config and are working in a *virtualhost* context, you shouldn't really be using mod_rewrite for this. You should create a separate vhost, one for `domain1`, the other for `domain2` and use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive instead... less prone to error, more efficient.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.org.uk
    ServerAlias www.domain1.org.uk
    RedirectMatch 301 ^ https://www.domain2.org.uk/specific-page/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain2.org.uk
    ServerAlias www.domain2.org.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog logs/mkt-error_log
    CustomLog logs/mkt-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

NB: These vhosts are only for HTTP (port 80), so you will naturally need to repeat this redirect for HTTPS (port 443).

Comment: That almost works for me. Now www.domain1.org.uk redirects to www.domain2.org.uk/specific-page/ but domain1.org.uk redirects to www.domain2.org.uk. I don't really understand why that is. Could this be because I have Cloudfare and that is affecting it? That's how I get the switch from http to https to work for example. Thanks

Comment: "Could this be because I have Cloudfare" - quite possibly. Check what page rules you have defined. This certainly isn't caused by the directives posted above.